# Header file with FNM_EXTMATCH

Tags: c, header-files

Everything goes well with this statement:

```
fnmatch(pattern, href, FNM_EXTMATCH);
```

when I oder the header files as below:

```
#include <fnmatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "link.h"
```

But the gcc says that FNM_EXTMATCH not defined when I order the head files instead as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>
#include "link.h"
```

So where is the conflict?

Answer (score 3):

`FNM_EXTMATCH` is a GNU extension. If you wish to use it, put

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

at the top of your file (before any `#include` statements). Note, however, that it will not be portable to non-GNU systems -- those without gcc and glibc.